# Reading Unread emails (gmail) using Blue Prism Bots

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am trying to get Gmail Inbox unread emails as a collection and process the emails in the queue using Blue Prism tool. I am not able to get the table element for the unread emails so that I can process that table element in the collection. 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow and edit your question.

Comment: Spy a single row in Gmail and then use a dynamic attribute to loop through each of the rows on the page.

Comment: Alternatively, use an IMAP wrapper object to retrieve the contents of the mailbox programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Email-POP3/SMTP VBO for getting the emails using BP, than you can get the required data and put into a queue as per your need. 
Please watch the video for more details : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUVwBu5L1jU.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51YaB.png)